An Azure Functions project function is not populating a parameter using [FromBody]
Using .Net 8, I have created an Azure Function project.  In my function, I want to populate the accountRequest object in the parameters.  I attempted to get the accountRequest by adding an [FromBody] attribute, but .NET does not map it.  I can get the body by using a HttpRequest req paramter like  req.ReadFromJsonAsync<AccountRequest>, but I would rather use FromBody for simplicity.  Is there a way to do this, or do I need to rely on req.ReadFromJsonAsync<AccountRequest>()
Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "PriceList/GetAllPriceList")]
    [FromBody] AccountRequest accountRequest)
{
    // accountRequest is null
} 

Project details:
My project is referring to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App and the Microsoft.NETCore.App frameworks.  It also references a number of Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker packages including Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.SDK, Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http, Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http.AspNetCore.  My project includes a class 'AccountRequest' defined as:
public class AccountRequest
{
    public string? AccountId { get; set; }
}

I am posting json to the method using Postman: { "AccountId": "bed94a30-0fc5-ea11-a812-000d3a531257" }
The Program class Main method has the following:
var host = new HostBuilder().ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()…

This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59985215/azure-functions-3-and-frombody-modelbinding

@RuiJarimba I saw that, but it did not resolve my issue.

I have modified my code as below to get the value of AccountId using [FromBody] attribute in .Net8 isolated function.
Function.cs-
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net;

namespace _78391282
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "PriceList/GetAllPriceList")] HttpRequestData req, 
            [FromBody] AccountRequest accountRequest)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.WriteString($"Account Id is: {accountRequest.AccountId}");
            return response;
        }
    }
    public class AccountRequest
    {
        public string? AccountId { get; set; }
    }
}

Program.cs file looks like below-
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

I have following packages in .csproj file.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RootNamespace>_78391282</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I am able to get the expected response upon invoking the function URL.



What did you do man ? Expecting everyone to parse a wall of text to find your fix wth?

@JKJ I have added all the relevant files as complete code was not present in the OP and also its a test code which I have used. It will help the community members to get to see the complete code

Your change seemed to have been the usage of 'ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults'. But it didn't help me unfortunately.

@JKJ Yes initially isolated function was using by default ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults which comes with Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http package but after the integration of ASP.NET core, its using ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication() as well Which doesn't have Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http package, so while using ASP.NET core intergration in isolated function you need to explicitly add using FromBodyAttribute = Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http.FromBodyAttribute;
